# TensorFlow evaluate test set and save predictions to a file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like you to point me to TensorFlow code that is scoring the test set, without labels, Kaggle competition style (image_id, predicted_class or list of softmax values for each class to use ARGMAX later).
[Here is the original source code from solution I am evaluating now](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/eval_image_classifier.py).

Currently I have trained and saved model, evaluated on small validation set.
I wanted to simulate the real life scoring system, that will:

- Take images converted and pre-processed as TFrecords - I have this bit done.
- read in DNN architecture, and saved model state - have flags set up correctly in above solution
- Create a queue / batches - not sure where this queuing happening in this script
- Make predictions on batches or sharded TFrecords, and save them with image id to whatever human readable format (csv, txt etc.) in format, picture ID, predicted class or list of probabilities for each class.
- My problem is the three class classification.

The best analogy I can use is, to use Keras - like model.predict(x_test ...)

I do not understand correctly how this works in either TensorFlow or tf.contrib.Slim.
Does Slim have such functionality?

How can I create my x_test.
I am after modifying this solution and customizing it to a different problem.
But for simplicity we could assume that I am using above solution to train and evaluate.
Above script calculates classification accuracy, I can't find, which part of code it is, that I could extract pure predictions from.  Instead of calculating accuracy. I would like to do the validation, visually myself.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at `tf.estimator.Estimator`, as it was designed to make it easy to run the same model with different inputs and different objectives.

Comment: I think I got this all wrong. Now after discovering TensorFlow for poets tutorial, I would like to achieve same effect as in tutorial. Which is having trained model as checkpoint .ckpt, freeze it to protocol buffer using this script freeze_graph.py, and score new images like in this [example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#5) However the problem I am encountering is to discover what is the softmax layer node name in this tf.slim [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py). How to find final layer in graph?

Comment: Using tf.estimator.Estimator is a better way of getting automatic predictions.

Comment: Would you have any particular example in mind? Could you share it please?